# Prestasop 1.6 - No Subject was found for bankwire in the database

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to translate the emails and in some it gives error "No Subject was found for bankwire in the database.

But only some emails from both the Core and Modules.

List of all core emails where "No Subject was found for bankwire in the database."

```
bankwire
cheque
employee_password
newsletter
order_canceled
order_conf_cart_rules
order_conf_product_list
outofstock
payment_error
payment
preparation
refund
shipped
voucher_new
```

Answer (score 0):

The subject of bankwire mail is taken from the Orders / Statuses

[image]